# Substring Query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, split, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table with 2 columns in below format . I want to get all strings from `Col1` which starts from end of word of `col2` as separate columns.

For example: If `Col1` has `ABC:EFG:MNO:XYZ` and `Col2` has `MNO`, then output would have `L1` as `XYZ` ( data between string of `Col2` and end of `Col1`)

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC:EFG:MNO:XYZ | MNO |
| PQR:NOM:XYN:SDF:RST:EDF | NOM |

I want to get below output.

| L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 | L5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ |  |  |  |  |
| XYN | SDF | RST | EDF |  |

I tried to use substring but that didn't work for me.

Regards

Comment: Can you explain in words how you get from the input to the output?  I assume `col1` is a string delimited by colons.  But why are some values excluded in the output?  Why are some values in the `l1` column versus one of the `l2` columns?  Additionally, a result set can't have two identically named columns so you can't have four columns all named `l2`.  Did you intend for the columns to be named `l1` through `l5`?

Comment: Was your intention for the `col1` value in the second row to be `PQR:NOW:...` rather than `PQR:NOM` so that the logic was to parse out the first 5 `col1` values that appear after the `col2` value and present them in the output?

Comment: Hi. I have added the details. Yes row2 was typo

Comment: OK.  What about the four columns in the result named `l2`?  Are you guaranteed that there will be exactly 5 columns in the result set?

Comment: Yes there will be only 5 col at max.  some may have data in L1 some may have till L5 but nothing will be more than L5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you put it, such a query might do the job. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col1, col2) as
  3    -- sample data; you already have that in your table; don't type it
  4    (select 'ABC:EFG:MNO:XYZ'        , 'MNO' from dual union all
  5     select 'PQR:NOM:XYN:SDF:RST:EDF', 'NOM' from dual
  6    ),
  7  remainder as
  8    -- fetch part of COL1 that follows the COL2 value
  9    (select col1, col2,
 10       substr(col1, instr(col1, col2) + length(col2) + 1) col
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  -- finally, extract up to 5 "words" (as your example suggests) from COL
 14  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) l1,
 15         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) l2,
 16         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) l3,
 17         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 4) l4,
 18         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 5) l5
 19  from remainder;

L1    L2    L3    L4    L5
----- ----- ----- ----- -----
XYZ
XYN   SDF   RST   EDF

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stored Function in order to pivot the results dynamically through use of Conditional Aggregation, after splitting the column `col1` by colons such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Splitted_Columns RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG('MAX( CASE WHEN rn2 =  '''||level||''' THEN col1 END ) AS "L_'||level||'"' , ',' )
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY level )
    INTO v_cols
    FROM dual
   CONNECT BY level <= ( SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(col1,':',INSTR(col1,col2))) FROM tab );
                            
  v_sql :='WITH t AS
          (
           SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,''[^:]+'',1,level) AS col1, col2, level AS rn,
                  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS dr              
             FROM tab
          CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(col1,'':'')+1
              AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
              AND PRIOR col1 = col1
          ), t2 AS
          (
           SELECT t.*,MAX(CASE WHEN col1=col2 THEN rn END) OVER (PARTITION BY dr) AS max_rn
             FROM t
          ), t3 AS
          (
           SELECT dr, max_rn, rn, rn - max_rn AS rn2, col1, col2 
             FROM t2 tt
            WHERE rn > ( SELECT MAX(max_rn) FROM t2 WHERE dr = tt.dr )
          )
          SELECT '||v_cols||'
            FROM t3
           GROUP BY dr';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call the function as

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Splitted_Columns;
PRINT rc
```

from *SQL Developer*'s command line

<kbd>[Demo for Generated SQL by Function](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ca428bcae8a556689f3d1a6ce9582ae8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Well if nothing has more than L5 and you always have three letters just hardcode it with the offset of the first match.

```
WITH tab AS (
  SELECT 'ABC:EFG:MNO:XYZ'         AS Col1, 'MNO' AS Col2 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'PQR:NOM:XYN:SDF:RST:EDF' AS Col1, 'NOM' AS Col2 FROM DUAL
)

SELECT tab.Col1,
       tab.Col2,
       SUBSTR(tab.Col1, NULLIF(INSTR(tab.Col1, tab.Col2), 0) +  4, 3) AS L1,
       SUBSTR(tab.Col1, NULLIF(INSTR(tab.Col1, tab.Col2), 0) +  8, 3) AS L2,
       SUBSTR(tab.Col1, NULLIF(INSTR(tab.Col1, tab.Col2), 0) + 12, 3) AS L3,
       SUBSTR(tab.Col1, NULLIF(INSTR(tab.Col1, tab.Col2), 0) + 16, 3) AS L4,
       SUBSTR(tab.Col1, NULLIF(INSTR(tab.Col1, tab.Col2), 0) + 20, 3) AS L5
FROM   tab;
```

You find the first match with INSTR and use a 3 char substring starting from the match + entry * 4. NULLIF for the case, that there is no match.